# Rails NameError uninitialized constant (Model and Namespace Collision)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a model named `Organization`.  It is defined in `app/models/organization.rb`

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
... code
end
```

I have a controller named `Admin::Organization::ActivitiesController`.  It is defined in `app/controllers/admin/organization/activities_controller.rb`.  It has an index action in it.

```
class Admin::Organization::ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @organization = Organization.new
    ... more code
  end
end
```

I get the following message when I execute the above index action:

```
NameError in Admin::Organization::ActivitiesController#index
uninitialized constant Admin::Organization::ActivitiesController::Organization
```

For some reason it's scoping the Organization model inside the controller class.  If I change the `index` method to use

```
@organization = ::Organization.new
```

then it works fine.

This behavior doesn't seem to appear in a pry console.  If I add a `binding.pry` call in the index method, then I can call `Organization.new` or `::Organization.new` from the command line it works fine.

Every other model in the app works correctly and doesn't have this weird behavior.  I didn't write the code originally so I'm trying to figure out what is going on.

I think it might have something do with a namespace in the routes.rb file.  There is a namespace that uses the `organization` word.

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :organization
    resources :activities
  end
end
```

As a test, I changed the namespace to `:organizations`, and I was able to get things to work without needing `::`.  Is there a way to structure things, or a routing setting, so we can have a namespace of `:organization` that doesn't interfere with the model named `Organization`?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "the code breaks", do you mean you see that error when you try and start the app or when you call the `ActivitiesController#index` method?

Comment: It breaks when the `ActivitiesController#index` action is executed.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make the path correct, you don't require to put the activities controller under `admin/organization` namespace folder. Another option would be like using scope instead of namespace.

```
# app/controllers/activities_controller.rb
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @organization = Organization.new
    ... more code
  end
end
```

Now configure routes,

```
# config/routes.rb
scope 'admin/organization', path: 'admin/organization'  do
  resources :activities
end
```

This will produce routes like this,

```
Prefix Verb   URI    Pattern                                      Controller#Action

activities    GET    /admin/organization/activities(.:format)     activities#index
              POST   /admin/organization/activities(.:format)     activities#create
......
```